# How to install this github ruby(gem) project on my ubuntu system?

Tags: ruby, github, repository

I am new to Ruby and this project is a ruby gem.
Link to the project https://github.com/cheerfulstoic/music.
I can't find any steps to setup this project.

Comment: Have a look at [rubygems.org](http://rubygems.org). Here you can search and find gems, get gem information and see the gem popularity. Here is [music](https://rubygems.org/gems/music).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a Ruby [gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/music).

Just install it manually:

```
gem install music
```

or add the following to your Gemfile, when your project uses Bundler:

```
gem 'music'
```